# Generic Find Method on Repository using Mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb, generics, repository

I am trying to make a generic repository with a find operation that takes an expression. I have the following right now (I am using FastMapper for projecting from my entity objects to an external contract object):

```
    public override List<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var collection = _database.GetCollection<Y>(_collectionName);
        return collection.AsQueryable<Y>().Project().To<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
    }
```

The problem is I get the following exception: "Where with predicate after a projection is not supported."

I can do the following, but this would severely poor performance wise because it would involve retrieving every record from the database before performing the filtering:

```
    public override List<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var collection = _database.GetCollection<Y>(_collectionName);
        return collection.AsQueryable<Y>().Project().To<T>().ToList().AsQueryable().Where(predicate).ToList();
    }
```

I am wondering if there is a way to convert the expression from a T to a Y object so that I could do the following instead (which I think would be the most performant because it then passes the filtering down to the database and only performs Project on the resultset):

```
    public override List<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var collection = _database.GetCollection<Y>(_collectionName);
        return collection.AsQueryable<Y>().Where(predicate).Project().To<T>().ToList();
    }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**

So, using the information from this question ([Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667561/convert-expression-trees)) I was able to get closer to what I was looking for. I am now able to do the following:

```
    public override List<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var newPredicate = TransformPredicateLambda<T, Y>(predicate);
        var collection = _database.GetCollection<Y>(_collectionName);
        return collection.AsQueryable<Y>().Where(newPredicate).Project().To<T>().ToList();
    }
```

The only thing I have left to resolve is retrieving the fastmapper mappings at this point (if property is null part):

```
        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            var dataContractType = node.Member.ReflectedType;
            var activeRecordType = _typeConverter(dataContractType);

            var property = activeRecordType.GetProperty(node.Member.Name);

            if (property == null)
            {

            }
            var converted = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                    base.Visit(node.Expression),
                    property
                    );

                return converted;


        }
```

essentially, some of my objects might look like this:

```
//object used throughout my code
public class Store
{
     public string StoreId {get; set;}

     public Account Account {get; set;}
     ...
}

//object used in access layer only
public class Store 
{
     public string StoreId {get; set;}

     public string AccountId {get; set;}
     ...
}
```

And in my initialization script, I define a type adapter like so:

```
            TypeAdapterConfig<Store, Models.Store>.NewConfig()
            .MapFrom(a => a.Id, s => s.StoreId != null ? new ObjectId(s.StoreId) : new ObjectId())
            .MapFrom(d => d.AccountId, s => s.Account.AccountId)
            .IgnoreNullValues(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't do a projection from Y to T prior to handing the query to MongoDB is that MongoDB doesn't know anything about T. We only know about Y (because that is the type of the collection). For instance:

```
class Person
{
  [BsonElement("fn")]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  [BsonElement("ln")]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class PersonView
{
  public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

And your projector does something like this:

```
person => new PersonView { FullName = person.FirstName + person.LastName }
```

We don't have access to the code in the projector and have no idea that FullName is the concatenation of FirstName and LastName and therefore can't tell MongoDB to do this.

The LINQ support in the 1.x version of the driver cannot target the Aggregation Framework, which is the only place this would be legal, and only assuming your projector produced an `Expression<Func<Person, PersonView>>` and not a compiled `Func<Person, PersonView>`.  However, the 2.x version of the driver will have better support for this, although it really depends on what FastMapper does underneath.

======

So, your current options are this:

1. Change the method signature to be `Expression<Func<Y, bool>>`. This would not only satisfy your needs, but also limit the documents you are projecting to only those that pass the filter.
2. If T inherits from Y, you could start with an OfType and not even need the projector: `collection.AsQueryable<Y>().OfType<T>.Where(predicate).ToList();`

Comment: I want to separate my application logic from my data storage logic so I don't want to have the Mongo attributes on the model objects that I use throughout my application. I put a repository around the database interaction, with separate model objects that include all of the annotations for Mongo (this way the rest of my application doesn't know anything about the mongo elements, and if I moved to Cassandra instead, I wouldn't have to modify the objects that the application uses at all, just the repository and the objects it uses). That is why I don't want to expose Y outside the repository.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, sorta. The current driver doesn't support projecting before a filter. Even if it was supported, MongoDB would not perform well because it cannot apply an index after a projection. So, you're going to need to come up with another solution. Have a method encapsulate the operation you want to do. Instead of taking a predicate, call the method GetPeopleWithFirstName(string firstName) and let your DAL do it's job as best it can.